# C# - Intercepting property changes in subclasses

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I'm in the process of creating a framework in which I provide the base class and the implementers of the framework will inherit from the base class and provide additional properties and methods.  In the base class, I would like to have a way of observing when a property value is changed.  The property can be from the base class or in any of the subclasses.  I know that through reflection, I can determine the list of properties from any instance, but is there a way I can track the property changing value?

Here is a very simplistic example of what I am saying:

```cs
public class BaseClass
{
    public string BaseClassProperty { get; set; }

    public void DoSomethingWhenEitherPropertyGetsChanged()
    {

    }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public string SubClassProperty { get; set; }
}
```

What can I do to have `DoSomethingWhenEitherPropertyGetsChanged` get executed when either of the properties has it's value changed.

Comment: even in the base class, you are going to have to call `DoSomethingWhenEitherPropertyGetsChanged()` in your property setter so you can do the same call in the setters of properties of subclass.

Comment: For anyone who's interested in implementing an interceptor, take a look at [TinyInterceptor](https://github.com/Jalalx/TinyInterceptor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `notifypropertyweaver` for this purpose.  It does exactly what you want.  Here's a link:

- [notifypropertyweaver](https://github.com/shiftkey/NotifyPropertyWeaver)

From the open source home page:

Uses IL weaving (via http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to inject INotifyPropertyChanged code into properties.

- No attributes required
- No references required
- No base class required
- Supports .net 3.5, .net 4, Silverlight 3, Silverlight 4, Silverlight 5 and Windows Phone 7
- Supports client profile mode

Comment: Thanks!  After a quick test, this seems to be just what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use Postsharp and create an inherited attribute injecting interception code into all public properties. Marking the attribute as inherited should also attach it to all subclasses automatically.

Comment: Are you saying that an attribute should be created on the `BaseClass` that will intercept the setter method on the all of the properties from the base class as well as any inherited classes?

Comment: Postsharp defines some attributes which basically let you inject code into all kinds of methods.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own idea of your requirements, but I am not sure if it suits your needs. INotifyProperty changed is something you could also look into, but I don't really like it because it is like wiring up speghetti. Maybe this will give you some creative ideas, though.

What this does, is allow you to use ObservableObject as for all of your properties types. By doing this, each property will have an ObjectChanged event you can wire-up to. The con(s) are that you must initialize all of your properties in the constructor to prevent a NullReferenceException somewhere in your code.

This example uses three classes.

- ObservableObject.cs
- Employee.cs
- Program.cs

**ObservableObject.cs**

```
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <copyright file="ObservableObject.cs" company="DCOM Productions">
    //     Copyright (c) DCOM Productions.  All rights reserved.
    // </copyright>
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    namespace PropertyChangedEventExample {
        using System;

        public class ObservableObject : Object {
            /// <summary>
            /// Expose the default constructor
            /// </summary>
            public ObservableObject() {
                // No default implementation
            }

            private object m_Object = null;
            /// <summary>
            /// Base object
            /// </summary>
            public object Object {
                get {
                    return m_Object;
                }
                set {
                    if (m_Object != value) {
                        m_Object = value;
                        OnObjectChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Triggered when the value of this object has changed.
            /// </summary>
            public event System.EventHandler<EventArgs> ObjectChanged;
            /// <summary>
            /// EventHandler wire-up
            /// </summary>
            protected virtual void OnObjectChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
                if (ObjectChanged != null) {
                    ObjectChanged(sender, e);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets the value
            /// </summary>
            public object Get() {
                return this.Object;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Sets the value
            /// </summary>
            public void Set(object value) {
                this.Object = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Employee.cs**

```
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <copyright file="Employee.cs" company="DCOM Productions">
    //     Copyright (c) DCOM Productions.  All rights reserved.
    // </copyright>
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    namespace PropertyChangedEventExample {
        using System;

        public class Employee {
            /// <summary>
            /// Expose default constructor
            /// </summary>
            public Employee() {
                Name = new ObservableObject();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the name
            /// </summary>
            public ObservableObject Name {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <copyright file="Program.cs" company="DCOM Productions">
    //     Copyright (c) DCOM Productions.  All rights reserved.
    // </copyright>
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    namespace PropertyChangedEventExample {
        using System;

        class Program {
            static void Main(string[] args) {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.Name.Set("David");
                employee.Name.ObjectChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Name_ObjectChanged);
                employee.Name.Set("Dave");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }

            static void Name_ObjectChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                ObservableObject employee = sender as ObservableObject;
                Console.WriteLine("Name changed to {0}", employee.Get());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be what CrisWue recommended and use postsharp or some other post-processor to inject the behavior in your properties. Other than that I think you would need to call DoSomethingWhenEitherPropertyGetsChanged() manually within your properties.

If you are creating a library that is consumed by people other than you or your organization, a post-processor may not be the right way to go as it adds the 3rd party tool as another requirement to their build process.